# Convert response from nodejs fs to web file api

Tags: node.js, fileapi

Got a package reading and parsing files in browser

```
<input multiple accept=".abc" name="file" id="txtFileUpload" type="file" onchange="upload(event)"/>

function upload(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    somepackage.read(file, function(error, data) {...}
```

I need to use the same package in nodejs

```
fs.readFile("somefile.abc", 'utf8' , (err, file) => {
    somepackage.read(file, function (error, data) {
   // gives error
```

The response from web browser api and response from node js fs is not the same. Is it possible to convert the response from node's fs so it is the same as in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the browser, the `file` variable will be an instance of `File` as described in the MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Meaning it's a complete object with properties like `name`, `lastModified`…

Meanwhile in Node.js the value returned by `fs.readFile` with the `utf8` encoding will be the content of the file as a string.

So they're indeed incompatible. Depending on what `somepackage.read` does with the `File` object, you may be able to emulate a dummy object by retrieving date info with a separate `fs.stat` call.

Fortunately, projects like https://github.com/node-file-api/file-api already took care of it.

Beware that if `somepackage.read` assume that the provided file is a `Blob`, you'll need to enhance the package mentioned above by using feature introduced very recently in Node.js 15.x : https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/36811